# Pasar valor de una funcion a otra funcion dentro de una clase

Tags: python-3.x, qt

Tengo una clase llamada MyApp. Dentro de esta clase tengo 3 funciones.

1. Busca la direccion de una carpeta mediante cuadro de dialogo.
2. Con la direccion de la carpeta se crea una lista de los archivos xml en dicha carpeta.

Yo quiero pasar el valor que retorna la funcion 1 hacia la función 2.

Lo he podido hacer en spyder. Pero ahora quiero pasar esto a una GUI echa en Qt Creator y ahi he tenido el problema.

De antemano les agradezco su apoyo.

Este es el codigo que tengo para Qt5

```
import sys
import os
import time
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

qtCreatorFile = "Extractor1.ui" 
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

lstFiles = [] #Lista vacia para incluir los ficheros
lstErrores=[] #Se usara para guardar los folios de facturas con errores

class MyApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.eligeCarpetaXML)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.archivoExcel)
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.listaXML)
        return

    def eligeCarpetaXML(self): #Elige la carpeta donde estan las facturas

        print("Elija la carpeta donde estan las facturas: ")
        Tk().withdraw()
        carpetaXML=filedialog.askdirectory()
        self.lineEdit.setText(carpetaXML)

        #Guardr la variable

        file=open("C:/Users/eguillaumin/Documents/Python/carpetaXML.txt", "w")
        file.write(carpetaXML+"/")  #Se guarda path en archivo txt
        file.close()

        return carpetaXML #Este valor necesito pasarlo como variable path a la funcion listaXML

    def listaXML(self,path):#(self,lineEdit): #Crea lista con facturas en formato XML
        #path=(self.lineEdit.text())
        lstDir=[]
        lstDir = os.walk(path)
        lstFiles = []
        x=0###
        for root, dirs, files in lstDir:
            for fichero in files:
                (nombreFichero, extension) = os.path.splitext(fichero)
                if(extension == ".xml"):
                    lstFiles.append(nombreFichero+extension)
                    x=x+1###
                    self.lcdNumber.display(len(lstFiles))

        cadena="---".join(lstFiles)#
        self.textBrowser.setText(cadena)#
        return lstFiles

    def archivoExcel(self): #Elige el archivo excel de salida

        print("Elija el archivo de excel donde guardara la información: ")
        Tk().withdraw()
        Archivoxls = askopenfilename()
        self.lineEdit_2.setText(Archivoxls)

        #Guardar la variable en un archivo

        file=open("C:/Users/eguillaumin/Documents/Python/ArchivoExcel.txt", "w") # Linea ORIGINAL
        file.write(Archivoxls)
        file.close()
        return Archivoxls


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app =  QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
```